# kendo numeric textbox configuration for restricting only two decimal values while entering in textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, textbox, decimal, numeric-textbox

kendo numerictextbox configuration for restricting only two decimal values while entered in textbox
please give the solution in jsfiddle if possible

For Example

The given input is `1666.66` if i enter third decimal value means it will not allow to enter

When the output has comes `1666.66`

For example:

- `123.44 = 123.44`
- `12000.56 = 12000.56`

Answer (score 0):

Use format to make it 2 points after decimal;

```
$("#hook").kendoNumericTextBox
({
      format: "#.00"
});
```